Using --mount=type=cache and --no-cache-dir Together in Docker RUN Instruction
In a Dockerfile, I am considering using both the --mount=type=cache and --no-cache-dir options together in a RUN instruction. For example:
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

I am trying to understand if using these two options together is effective or necessary. Specifically, I want to know how the --mount=type=cache option for caching interacts with the --no-cache-dir option that prevents caching during the pip install command.
I am seeking clarification on whether combining --mount=type=cache with --no-cache-dir achieves any practical benefit or if it results in conflicting behavior. My expectation is to understand the implications and best practices for caching dependencies in Docker builds.
